# Random freezes at bootup, plus issues with power management on an Asus X556UJ (F556U series)

Tags: boot, kernel, 16.04, laptop, asus

I just bought a new Asus F556U series laptop that `dmidecode` identifies as X556UJ.

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
        Product Name: X556UJ
        Version: 1.0       
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: ASUS-NotebookSKU
        Family: X
```

On this laptop I transferred the `Ubuntu 16.04` installation I had on the previous (now broken) laptop.

### Bootup freezes

At boot up very often I get random freezes: basically, after the usual Ubuntu splash screen, X won't start and the screen will stay blank.

### Power management issues

Suspending to ram freezes the system too. Moreover, the battery indicator never shows when the laptop is being charged with the power cord, it always assumes it's running off the battery even when it's not.

---

I don't know whether it's related to the issue, but this is what I found in `/var/log/kern.log

```
[   41.430855] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   41.430871] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 214 at /build/linux-kEu4j9/linux-4.4.0/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_irq.c:1317 drm_wait_one_vblank+0x17b/0x1c0 [drm]()
[   41.430872] vblank not available on crtc 0, ret=-22
[   41.430890] Modules linked in: pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) binfmt_misc rtsx_usb_ms memstick nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_mod
eset(POE) nvidia(POE) uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media btusb btrtl snd_soc_skl arc4 snd_soc_skl_ipc rtl8723be snd_hda_ext_core btc
oexist rtl8723_common snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_core intel_rapl rtl_pci rtlwifi snd_hda_codec_hdmi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_compress ac97_bus coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengin
e snd_hda_codec_realtek dw_dmac_core snd_hda_codec_generic crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec crc32_pclmul snd_hda_core joydev mac80211 aesni_intel asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_w
mi snd_hwdep cfg80211 aes_x86_64 i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event lrw gf128mul glue_helper snd_rawmidi ablk_helper snd_seq wmi cryptd snd_seq_devic
e snd_timer elan_i2c snd input_leds serio_raw kvm_intel kvm intel_lpss_acpi irqbypass int3403_thermal processor_thermal_device idma64 virt_dma hci_uart btbcm btqca int3402_thermal btintel mei_me blu
etooth soundcore acpi_pad intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss mei shpchp int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel tpm_crb intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid cuse parport_pc ppdev nfsd lp auth_rpcgss nfs_
acl lockd grace sunrpc parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb uas usb_storage i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 d
rm mii ahci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint pinctrl_intel video fjes
[   41.430910] CPU: 2 PID: 214 Comm: plymouthd Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-25-generic #44-Ubuntu
[   41.430911] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. X556UJ/X556UJ, BIOS X556UJ.404 05/09/2016
[   41.430913]  0000000000000286 00000000764b65d7 ffff880035a3b710 ffffffff813eb103
[   41.430913]  ffff880035a3b758 ffffffffc00b6ae8 ffff880035a3b748 ffffffff81081102
[   41.430914]  ffff8800359e5000 0000000000000000 ffff88003542d800 ffff8800359e5368
[   41.430914] Call Trace:
[   41.430918]  [<ffffffff813eb103>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[   41.430920]  [<ffffffff81081102>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[   41.430921]  [<ffffffff8108119c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[   41.430928]  [<ffffffffc0087054>] ? drm_vblank_get+0x74/0xc0 [drm]
[   41.430933]  [<ffffffffc00872ab>] drm_wait_one_vblank+0x17b/0x1c0 [drm]
[   41.430956]  [<ffffffffc01c7720>] ? gen9_write16+0x380/0x380 [i915_bpo]
[   41.430968]  [<ffffffffc01c7720>] ? gen9_write16+0x380/0x380 [i915_bpo]
[   41.430977]  [<ffffffffc0179b6a>] skl_update_wm+0x4ba/0x5f0 [i915_bpo]
[   41.430986]  [<ffffffffc017d55e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
[   41.431000]  [<ffffffffc01e9571>] haswell_crtc_enable+0x321/0x8c0 [i915_bpo]
[   41.431013]  [<ffffffffc01e5f28>] intel_atomic_commit+0x5f8/0xdc0 [i915_bpo]
[   41.431023]  [<ffffffffc00a07de>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
[   41.431031]  [<ffffffffc00a0c17>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
[   41.431037]  [<ffffffffc01376ff>] restore_fbdev_mode+0x22f/0x260 [drm_kms_helper]
[   41.431046]  [<ffffffffc009f4aa>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
[   41.431050]  [<ffffffffc01398d3>] drm_fb_helper_restore_fbdev_mode_unlocked+0x33/0x80 [drm_kms_helper]
[   41.431053]  [<ffffffffc013994d>] drm_fb_helper_set_par+0x2d/0x50 [drm_kms_helper]
[   41.431066]  [<ffffffffc01fbafa>] intel_fbdev_set_par+0x1a/0x60 [i915_bpo]
[   41.431068]  [<ffffffff8146e416>] fb_set_var+0x236/0x460
[   41.431071]  [<ffffffff810b341a>] ? select_idle_sibling+0x2a/0x120
[   41.431072]  [<ffffffff810b8b34>] ? enqueue_task_fair+0xa4/0x8b0
[   41.431073]  [<ffffffff810b3b35>] ? select_task_rq_fair+0x625/0x700
[   41.431075]  [<ffffffff813b71a3>] ? __blk_run_queue+0x33/0x40
[   41.431076]  [<ffffffff8146470f>] fbcon_blank+0x30f/0x350
[   41.431078]  [<ffffffff814fb833>] do_unblank_screen+0xd3/0x1a0
[   41.431080]  [<ffffffff814f0e9a>] vt_ioctl+0x50a/0x12f0
[   41.431085]  [<ffffffffc0085779>] ? drm_ioctl+0x189/0x540 [drm]
[   41.431087]  [<ffffffff814e436f>] tty_ioctl+0x35f/0xc40
[   41.431089]  [<ffffffff818269f9>] ? schedule_hrtimeout_range_clock+0xb9/0x1b0
[   41.431091]  [<ffffffff8125615b>] ? ep_poll+0x37b/0x3d0
[   41.431093]  [<ffffffff81220acf>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
[   41.431094]  [<ffffffff810ac010>] ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
[   41.431095]  [<ffffffff81220d39>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[   41.431095]  [<ffffffff818275f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[   41.431096] ---[ end trace ec72379fbbe6d3b1 ]---
```

And again:

```
[   41.446577] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   41.446588] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 214 at /build/linux-kEu4j9/linux-4.4.0/ubuntu/i915/intel_pm.c:3586 skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]()
[   41.446589] WARN_ON(!wm_changed)
[   41.446600] Modules linked in: pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) binfmt_misc rtsx_usb_ms memstick nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common videodev media btusb btrtl snd_soc_skl arc4 snd_soc_skl_ipc rtl8723be snd_hda_ext_core btcoexist rtl8723_common snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_core intel_rapl rtl_pci rtlwifi snd_hda_codec_hdmi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_compress ac97_bus coretemp snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek dw_dmac_core snd_hda_codec_generic crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec crc32_pclmul snd_hda_core joydev mac80211 aesni_intel asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi snd_hwdep cfg80211 aes_x86_64 i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event lrw gf128mul glue_helper snd_rawmidi ablk_helper snd_seq wmi cryptd snd_seq_device snd_timer elan_i2c snd input_leds serio_raw kvm_intel kvm intel_lpss_acpi irqbypass int3403_thermal processor_thermal_device idma64 virt_dma hci_uart btbcm btqca int3402_thermal btintel mei_me bluetooth soundcore acpi_pad intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss mei shpchp int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel tpm_crb intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid cuse parport_pc ppdev nfsd lp auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb uas usb_storage i915_bpo intel_ips i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 drm mii ahci libahci i2c_hid hid pinctrl_sunrisepoint pinctrl_intel video fjes
[   41.446614] CPU: 2 PID: 214 Comm: plymouthd Tainted: P        W  OE   4.4.0-25-generic #44-Ubuntu
[   41.446614] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. X556UJ/X556UJ, BIOS X556UJ.404 05/09/2016
[   41.446615]  0000000000000286 00000000764b65d7 ffff880035a3b690 ffffffff813eb103
[   41.446616]  ffff880035a3b6d8 ffffffffc0247c98 ffff880035a3b6c8 ffffffff81081102
[   41.446617]  ffff88006a530000 ffff8800355b9d9c ffff88006a531000 ffff8800359e5378
[   41.446617] Call Trace:
[   41.446619]  [<ffffffff813eb103>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[   41.446620]  [<ffffffff81081102>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[   41.446621]  [<ffffffff8108119c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5c/0x80
[   41.446630]  [<ffffffffc017969c>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x16c/0x180 [i915_bpo]
[   41.446639]  [<ffffffffc0179836>] skl_update_wm+0x186/0x5f0 [i915_bpo]
[   41.446653]  [<ffffffffc02054ff>] ? intel_ddi_enable_transcoder_func+0x17f/0x260 [i915_bpo]
[   41.446662]  [<ffffffffc017d55e>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915_bpo]
[   41.446675]  [<ffffffffc01e9571>] haswell_crtc_enable+0x321/0x8c0 [i915_bpo]
[   41.446688]  [<ffffffffc01d5bee>] ? intel_finish_crtc_commit+0xe/0x10 [i915_bpo]
[   41.446692]  [<ffffffffc0136434>] ? drm_atomic_helper_commit_planes_on_crtc+0x154/0x270 [drm_kms_helper]
[   41.446705]  [<ffffffffc01e5f28>] intel_atomic_commit+0x5f8/0xdc0 [i915_bpo]
[   41.446714]  [<ffffffffc00a07de>] ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x18e/0x590 [drm]
[   41.446722]  [<ffffffffc00a0c17>] drm_atomic_commit+0x37/0x60 [drm]
[   41.446727]  [<ffffffffc01376ff>] restore_fbdev_mode+0x22f/0x260 [drm_kms_helper]
[   41.446735]  [<ffffffffc009f4aa>] ? drm_modeset_lock_all_ctx+0x9a/0xb0 [drm]
[   41.446739]  [<ffffffffc01398d3>] drm_fb_helper_restore_fbdev_mode_unlocked+0x33/0x80 [drm_kms_helper]
[   41.446742]  [<ffffffffc013994d>] drm_fb_helper_set_par+0x2d/0x50 [drm_kms_helper]
[   41.446755]  [<ffffffffc01fbafa>] intel_fbdev_set_par+0x1a/0x60 [i915_bpo]
[   41.446756]  [<ffffffff8146e416>] fb_set_var+0x236/0x460
[   41.446758]  [<ffffffff810b341a>] ? select_idle_sibling+0x2a/0x120
[   41.446759]  [<ffffffff810b8b34>] ? enqueue_task_fair+0xa4/0x8b0
[   41.446760]  [<ffffffff810b3b35>] ? select_task_rq_fair+0x625/0x700
[   41.446761]  [<ffffffff813b71a3>] ? __blk_run_queue+0x33/0x40
[   41.446763]  [<ffffffff8146470f>] fbcon_blank+0x30f/0x350
[   41.446764]  [<ffffffff814fb833>] do_unblank_screen+0xd3/0x1a0
[   41.446765]  [<ffffffff814f0e9a>] vt_ioctl+0x50a/0x12f0
[   41.446771]  [<ffffffffc0085779>] ? drm_ioctl+0x189/0x540 [drm]
[   41.446772]  [<ffffffff814e436f>] tty_ioctl+0x35f/0xc40
[   41.446774]  [<ffffffff818269f9>] ? schedule_hrtimeout_range_clock+0xb9/0x1b0
[   41.446775]  [<ffffffff8125615b>] ? ep_poll+0x37b/0x3d0
[   41.446776]  [<ffffffff81220acf>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
[   41.446776]  [<ffffffff810ac010>] ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
[   41.446777]  [<ffffffff81220d39>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[   41.446778]  [<ffffffff818275f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[   41.446779] ---[ end trace ec72379fbbe6d3b2 ]---
```

Then this gets printed:

```
[   42.991165] bbswitch: version 0.8
[   42.991171] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   42.991175] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.RP01.PEGP
[   42.991183] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.RP01.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150930/nsarguments-95)
[   42.991236] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   42.991243] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
```

Subsequently, the laptop either freezes or continues with booting.

I installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers provided with Ubuntu, but the very same issue presented itself also without them.

**Notice** I had to add the `pci=noaer` option to the kernel, or else there'd be  a flood of messages as described in bug report [#1521173](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173).